# should you ask questions with the intention of answering it yourself

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Is this frowned up on/discouraged? The reason I ask is that I might do this so that I can use the question link somewhere else where I cannot type latex.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/recently-rolled-out-se-encyclopedia-feature, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/views-on-asking-and-answering-questions-solely-to-make-results-available-on-stac (And several other discussions are linked there.)

Comment: However if you want to do this *solely* for the reason that you want share some text and you need TeX rendering, there are more appropriate solutions, such as http://mathb.in/ or https://www.writelatex.com/ (You wrote in the OP: *so that I can use the question link somewhere else where I cannot type latex.*) See also [post about online editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) on TeX.SE. (Of course, if the text you want to share is suitable as question and answer here, it is perfectly ok to post it here.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak i would make sure it is a good question. i intend use the link for 'interesting undergraduate level questions'

Comment: Imagine that someone walks up to you and says, "Here is a question I am wondering about". They explain the question and then, just after you start thinking how to best answer it, they cut you off to say "Here's the answer ...".

Answer (score 7):

Self-answering your questions is an intended use of the sites, there is even a checkbox for you to post question and answer simultaneously:

[image]

However, you should still make it a **good** question, don't spend all your energy on the answer. If the question is poor, it will be downvoted, closed, deleted maybe, just like other poor questions.

If you do a good job, you will even get upvotes for both, question and answer.

Comment: I think this answer encourages self-answers a little too strongly. If someone asks a question in good faith and happens to work out the answer, then it is nice for them to type it up. But when someone asks a question *that they do not actually have a question about*, without indicating that, it is hard to see it as good faith. On the other hand, if they clearly indicate that they plan on answering the question themselves when asking it, that will let others know the situation.

Comment: Hm, I didn't mean to _encourage_ self-answered questions, I'm not a big fan of them myself. Just not _discourage_, since it's officially supported and intended functionality.

Comment: @CarlMummert: When one uses the "Answer your own question" checkbox, one is presented with the question box and answer box at the same time, so that (ideally) the question never appears to others without the asker's answer already being present.

Comment: @CarlMummert And why is it that it would be not good faith to post a question that you don't actually have a question about? I think you are confusing the role of this site. Rather than being The Reputation Hoarder online game (Mathematics campaign) it seems to me this is a site for questions and answers. Who cares where the questions and the answers come from.

Comment: I think that this answer explains the situation well: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1841/630 . This site is not about simply "hoarding" questions and answers - it is about *answering* questions that other people have asked. Having good questions and answers is part of the goal, but another key part of math.SE is interaction. If someone just wants to publish text, there are many superior venues (arXiv.org and personal websites/blogs are both better for that purpose).  Think of it like a department tea - nobody comes to hear someone talk to himself; they come to talk to other people.